# Pigeon hole problem unknown pigeons numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I am trying to solve an exercise but I am not sure if I handle it right.

> let's suppose we have 40 letters of the alphabet. The 20 of those are
> with small letters and 20 are with capital.What are the minimum numbers
> of the letters that have a text with capital letters, so that the text
> to contain at least 10 same letters?

what I have tried:
The 20 smaller letters can be ignored because we only want to learn about 20  capital letters.The text is in capital so we only care about 20.

Now I have lets call it a variable n.The variable n represents the pigeons(which is the text),the text is unknown the length it has.What we know is ,that we care about pigeonholes that are 20.We need to place the n into 20 so that we will take 10 at least.

what I think is $n/20$  =10 that means n= 20*10 =200.
Am I right?

Comment: Th phrase "at least 10 same letters" is not quite clear. Do you mean that there is a letter that appears at least 10 times? It is worth noting that getting a letter twice needs 21 letters in the text (you can get 20 different capitals, but the 21st must match one of the others).

Comment: there is  a letter that appears at least 10 times

Comment: It's not clear what is being asked.  The minimum so it is at all possible is $10$ as if you have $10$ it is *possible* they are all the same and all capital.  There is no number that assures that if you have that number that you have at least one capital and 10 letters the same as you can always have a letter with no capitals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $20$ pigeonholes and want to know how many pigeons that you must have so that at least one of the pigeonholes has $10$ pigeons.  If all $20$ pigeonholes have $9$ pigeons, you will have accommodated $180$ pigeons.

Then, the next (i.e. $181$-th) pigeon will have to cause one of the pigeonholes to have $10$ pigeons.